# How can I create a self-extracting executable from the windows command line that accepts the default install directory as a parameter?

Tags: windows, command-line, zip, 7-zip, winzip

I have tried several different methods including winzip command line and 7zip, but I cannot find a method that will let me create a self-extracting executable that will extract to a specific directory on the user's system when they run the exe.  This can easily be done with the GUI on multiple zip softwares, but I cannot find one that can do it all from the command line.  If you know of a software that works, can you also please provide a sample command?